# Spring singleton class creating multiple instance

Tags: spring, singleton, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to make class as singleton and to make it below changes are done

```
 Beans.xml has this:

 <bean id="LdapUti" class="com.amazon.bpmsawsproxy.util.LdapUtil" scope="singleton" />

 LdapUtil class:

public class LdapUtil {
     private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LdapUtil.class);

     public DirContext GetLdapDirContext() throws NamingException {

        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
         env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

         env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "*********");

         env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "******");
         env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
         env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

         DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
         return ctx;}}
```

This is the unit test case written to test singleton class

```
       @Test
public void testSingleton(){
    LdapUtil ctx1 = new LdapUtil();

    LdapUtil ctx2 = new LdapUtil();

    assertEquals(System.identityHashCode(ctx1), System.identityHashCode(ctx2));

}
```

From the unit test case: I am getting two different hashcode which I believe it is creating more than one instance. Please let me know if I have missed someting

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note the class in not a singleton, only scope of the class is set to singleton in sping config xml.

You created new instances which are not managed by spring hence you are getting different hashcodes.